# React-Router <Link> reload current page then move to new link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reload

I have a settings page that loads things to my local storage and for some odd reason needs a reload for my home page to get this new data. So as a workaround to this, whenever the user clicks on the "home button" from `Settings.js`. I'd like to reload the current page then open this new link in this exact order.

---

```
<Link onClick={() => window.location.reload()} style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}to='/'>
    <h1 class="titleVertical">Quick Type</h1>
</Link>
```

Above, I attempt to reload the page once the text is clicked, then using `to` I hope to  open the home page `'/'`. But for some odd reason the following happens.

https://media.giphy.com/media/84PuHlLED46HLsgPwM/giphy.gif

page is reloaded

moves to home page

moves back to settings.js

**But it's very quick and quite hard to tell what is going on. Maybe it's this.**

moves to home page

page is reloaded

moves back to settings.js

---

How can I avoid this? If my  is clicked, I want to reload the current page then move to the specified url. Or if it is easier, move to the specified url, then reload that page.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Having to reload the page to sync state is a bit of a hacky workaround to the _real_ problem, which is that you likely need to be maintaining this state higher up the component tree (or with context) rather than forcing a reload so Home knows to get the info from local storage.

Comment: Sorry, i'm very new to this whole react thing and js in general. Is this `state` thing, a global variable that should be defined in my Home page?